# how to retrieve scores of google form in script when user submit her answers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I want to retrieve in my script, score of quiz google form after user submit answers.

Do you know method in appscript who retrieve this?
Thank's for help.

Comment: You can use a "trigger" that will cause a function to run when the Form is submitted.  You need to use an "On Form Submit" trigger.  An "On Form Submit" trigger can be added to the Form the spreadsheet, or both.  [My Help Document - Form Submit](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iEB_EwK2rvqHYBRPQsdc4rKODSO1WwyLpirm-edV10E/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the script below..

```
  function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // Get all the values in the header row.
var scoresCol = 0; // This var will be the index of the score column. 

for(var i = 0; i < headers[0].length; i++){ // Loop to find the index of the score column and set the index in the scoresCol var.
if(headers[0][i] == 'Score'){
scoresCol = i + 1; 
break;
  }
 }

var scores = ss.getRange(2, scoresCol, ss.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Get all values in that column. 

}
```